# How to install org-mac-link on MacOS?

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I am trying to install `org-mac-link` on my Mac. I have downloaded the file `org-mac-link.el` to `.emacs.d` and also customized the org group by typing `M-x customize-group RET org RET`, then expand the Modules section, and enabled `mac-link`. But when I use `(require 'org-mac-link)` in my init file `emacs` gives an error since it says it can not find `org-mac-link` file.

This is part of my `init` file:

```
 ;; org-mac-link
 (require 'org-mac-link)
 (add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda ()
   (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c g") 'org-mac-grab-link)))
```

Comment: Where is the page to download org-mac-link? I thought it's something you activate in org but I haven't managed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the directory where `org-mac-link.el` is located to `load-path`, putting something like:

```
(push (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d") load-path)
```

in your `init` file before the `require`

Comment: First I got a warning: ```Warning (initialization): Your ‘load-path’ seems to contain
 your ‘.emacs.d’ directory: /Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d
 This is likely to cause problems...
 Consider using a subdirectory instead, e.g.: /Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/lisp```. I created a `lisp` folder and copied `org-mac-link.el` to it. Now it works with the `org-mac-grab-link` command but when I use "C-c g" it says it is undefined.

Comment: That sounds like the org-mode-hook hasn't been run. Does this happen from a fresh Emacs as well?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "fresh Emacs". My Emacs version is `GNU Emacs 26.1` and my `Org mode` version is 9.1.14.

Comment: Sorry, "C-c g" works now when I am editing an `org` file.

Comment: I mean exiting emacs and starting it again. If you already had a buffer in org-mode before changing org-mode-hook, then that would have run the old version, and thus the keybinding would not have been done.